# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

In Xcode when I build the app using "Deployment Target" 6.0 or 6.1 it works fine but if I change the target to 7.0 or higher I get undefined symbols error. I've tried removing the framework and adding it back in but still can't seem to get it to build. Not sure if this makes a difference but I have to use "-all_load" for "Other Linker Flags" for this framework. I've also made sure that "Valid Architectures" has armv7 included but I still can't figure this out. Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
 "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
     __GLOBAL__I_a in G4XSwiper(DownSample.o)
     __GLOBAL__I_a in G4XSwiper(FskController.o)
     __GLOBAL__I_a in G4XSwiper(WavBuffer.o)
     __GLOBAL__I_a in G4XSwiper(AE_ManchesterRealTimeDecoder.o)
     __GLOBAL__I_a in G4XSwiper(AE_ManchesterState.o)
 "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
     __GLOBAL__I_a in G4XSwiper(DownSample.o)
     __GLOBAL__I_a in G4XSwiper(FskController.o)
     __GLOBAL__I_a in G4XSwiper(WavBuffer.o)
     __GLOBAL__I_a in G4XSwiper(AE_ManchesterRealTimeDecoder.o)
     __GLOBAL__I_a in G4XSwiper(AE_ManchesterState.o)
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set **-ObjC -lstdc++** in *Other Linker Flags* or add the **libstdc++.6.dylib** in *Project->Targets->Build Phases-> Link Binary With Libraries*.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! I already had -ObjC and -lstdc++ added. I couldn't find libstdc++.6.dylib but I did add libstdc++.6.tbd and it worked. Why is this lib needed? Do you know? Thanks for the help.